# Regex to find everything between two html tags

Tags: python, regex

I have an HTML that looks like this:

```
<h1>Health Authority Updates</h1> 
<h3>hellow</h3>
<ol></ol>
<ol></ol>
<h1>Points to consider on COVID-19 and Regeneron’s programs</h1>
```

I want to get all the tags and everything in them including `<h1>Health Authority Updates</h1>` and excluding `<h1>Points to consider on COVID-19 and Regeneron’s programs</h1>`

I have tried this regex but it is not working:

```
<h1>Health Authority Updates</h1>.*[A-Za-z\/<>]
```

Comment: `r'h1>Health Authority Updates<\/h1>.+?(?=<h1)'`

Comment: @LeiYang not working either.

Comment: Important reading: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = '''<h1>Health Authority Updates</h1> 
<h3>hellow</h3>
<ol></ol>
<ol></ol>
<h1>Points to consider on COVID-19 and Regeneron’s programs</h1>'''
import re

print(re.search(r'h1>Health Authority Updates<\/h1>.+?(?=<h1)', s, re.DOTALL).group(0))
```

output:

```
h1>Health Authority Updates</h1> 
<h3>hellow</h3>
<ol></ol>
<ol></ol>
```

Comment: Just for learning purposes, what will be the regex for when I want to include everything after <h1>Health Authority Updates</h1>

Comment: `re.search(r'<h1>Health Authority Updates<\/h1>(.+)', s, re.DOTALL).group(1)`